# ng-select not retaining dropdown values after selection

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a drop-down to render some values with API. The values are rendering fine in the dropdown options. But, when I chose any option the value is not retained in the UI.

Here is my html:

```
<md-input-container md-no-float layout-fill style="text-align: start; margin-bottom: 25px !important;"> 
    <md-select ng-model="data_selected" placeholder="I want to speak..." required> 
     <md-option ng-repeat="lan in language_country" ng-value="{{lan}}">    {{lan.name}} 
     </md-option> 
   </md-select> 
</md-input-container>
```

---

Do I need to other things or did I misplaced any?

Comment: Is the selected value is not reflecting on controller or it's not doing the selection while loading the selected from DB?

Comment: can you post the json?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs with `ng-value`. Try using `value` instead of `ng-value` and your problem will be solved.

```
<md-select ng-model="data_selected" placeholder="I want to speak..." required> 
   <md-option ng-repeat="lan in language_country" value="{{lan}}">
      {{lan.name}} 
   </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change to **ng-options** directive will solve your problem.

**[ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)**

```
<md-input-container md-no-float layout-fill style="text-align: start; margin-bottom: 25px !important;"> 
    <md-select ng-model="data_selected" placeholder="I want to speak..." required 
        ng-options="lan.id as lan.name for lan in language_country"> 
     </md-select> 
</md-input-container>
```

Normal **md-option** used when you need to bind custom option to select or binding custom options.

```
<md-select ng-model="data_selected" placeholder="I want to speak..." required> 
   <md-option value="">Select Language</md-option>
   <md-option ng-repeat="lan in language_country" value="{{lan}}">
      {{lan.name}} 
   </md-option>
</md-select>
```